# User image upload to page gallery

Tags: facebook-graph-api, upload, photo

I've been hacking away for hours in the attempt to allow a user to upload an image to a page gallery.

The user(s) do not own and are not admins of the page. The user(s) is/are fans of the page.

The app I have set up has all of the permissions set and I'm using the access key generated for it.

I've returned the OG data to ensure I'm using the correct album id.

Am I correct in thinking that this is simply not possible?
Also is there an access key for the page itself that can be generated?

Thanks.

Comment: You are correct, currently there isn't a way to upload a photo to a Page's album. There is a Page Access token that can be obtained if you are the admin of the page (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/access-tokens-and-types/). However, that will let you post the photo as the Page, not as the user.